# How to add addition order item info in Order email in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, blocks, order-email

I want to add addition info of order item, Please check below image

[image]

I have added below code in config.xml but it is not working.

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <reference name="items">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>yourdirectory/order/items.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</sales_email_order_items>
```

Comment: Do you need to create new template file ?
Its working if moving base items.phtml file to your theme folder.

Comment: Yes, I am creating extension so I can't copy items.phtml in theme folder